# Language switcher to non-source language not working

Tags: i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I have a `Branch` content type, which also happens to be an [Organic Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). I use the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to set the URL to:

```
branch/[node:menu-link]
```

I have created a content, and a `Menu` with a menu item which linked to said content. Everything works well up until now.

Next I enabled [Entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) and translated it into two different languages (French and German). Since, with entity translation, the node ID will be the same, I don't need to change the link in the menu item.

When I go to the English (the default and source language) page, I see that in the 'Language Switcher (Content)' block, the other two languages are not linking. However, manually changing the language prefix in the URL worked. So, the page actually exists.

```
/en/branch/my-branch ----> /fr/branch/my-branch
```

When I am on the French page, the language switcher shows 'English' as clickable, but German is disabled. The same for the German page.

So it appears that the language switcher doesn't link to non-source languages. Is this a bug? Any pointer are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This looks really similar to what is described in [Language switcher (content) does not work](https://www.drupal.org/node/1904584), which is an issue on D.O that is not yet resolved (status = active).